# Добавление файла в удаленный репозиторий git

Tags: git

Здравствуйте, у меня при сохранении файла в удаленном репозитории git немного изменяется форматирование кода. Добавляются лишние пробелы. Можно ли из git подправить конечное форматирование?

Comment: Здесь нет примеров того, как именно изменяется форматирование. Без них можно только догадываться о проблеме и возможном решении. Тем более, автор больше не заходит на сайт с 5 апреля. Поэтому предлагаю вопрос закрыть как не по теме - неконструктивный.

Answer (score 2):

Файлы портятся при передаче через Git? Это на Windows?

Единственное место, где я помню, что Git сам вмешивается в файл (кроме слияния, применения патчей и т.д.), это обработка окончаний строк (CR/CRLF). Если поставить опцию `core.autocrlf` в`false`, проблема воспроизводится?

Как вы определяете, что появились пробелы? Есть пример "до/после"?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать hook pre-commit и запускать какую-нибудь утилиту или простой скрипт, который будет изменять форматирование.
Про то, как использовать хуки хорошо описано в [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0).